# Using TempData in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have stored a variable as TempData["ReqNo"]

```
ViewBag.TransNum = TempData["ReqNo"];
TempData.Keep();
```

I have a jQuery DataGrid Table that I populate with

```
var q = db.ICS_Orders;
```

I have been trying to add a WHERE Clause using the value of TempData but no matter what I try, I cannot get it to work.  I have looked all over, online, and found very little help.

Was hoping someone could just give me a quick example of how to use TempData in linq.  I have the following

```
var currReq = TempData["ReqNo"];
q = q.Where(s => s.RequisitionNumber.Contains(currReq)).ToList();
```

The above is one of MANY variations I have tired.  With the above, I am getting the error "cannot convert object to string"

I tried to convert using .

```
Convert.ToString(currReq);
```

But that didn't help at all.

And to answer the question on everyone's mind :Why are you doing it like this?

Because, I am a newbie and I am finding my way.  I usually try to figure things out the best I can before asking for help.  I really can't find much information about using TempData values in linq online.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get variables back out of `TempData`, cast them back to their original type. So if `TempData["ReqNo"]` was assigned a string, you can get it back out with:

```
var currReq = (string)TempData["ReqNo"];
```

`Convert.ToString(foo)` or `foo.ToString()` are for getting the string representation of a non-string object. Since the object in `TempData["ReqNo"]` was originally a string, you don't need to use a convert function, just a cast back to the original type.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  That worked, as far as not getting anymore errors in the linq statement.  But now I am puzzled, because the Jquery Table comes back empty now.  var q = db.ICS_Orders; And return View(q); bring back ALL the records. But when I change to:  var w = db.ICS_Orders.Where(s => s.RequisitionNumber == currReq);  And return View(w); The Table comes back empty.  Yet, when I create stops in the test environment, and I hover over 'currReq' it DOES have the value that I want.  Not sure why it's not bringing back any matching records.  They are there.

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct - because you have indeed answered my original question.  And I appreciate that.  The next problem is, most likely, a whole different question and will require me to post a lot of code. Therefore, I will ask that new question separately.  Thank you